# Laravel 5: Mime type validation issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have applied following rules:

```
            $this->validate($request, [
                'receiptfile' => 'mimes:png,jpeg,gif,pdf,doc'
            ]);
```

Then why .xls file is validated and passed from that rule on server which is not specified in rule at all. I have checked with multiple .xls files

Comment: Is it only xls or have you checked it against other file format type s

Comment: Checked with other file types xlsx which is throws invalid filetype error. Others seems, working fine

Comment: Does this understand that only xls is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

validation rule like below:

```
'receiptfile' => 'mimes:png,jpeg,gif,pdf,doc,xls,xlm,xla,xlc,xlt,xlw'
```

More type you can find below:

[mime types click here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)